# What is the pool during a deployment job in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I am using `ubuntu-latest` as my build vmImage for building all of my containers in my pipeline. Now I am trying to deploy a previously built container to AKS.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/aks-template?view=azure-devops), it is supposed to look like this:

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy job
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
```

Unfortunately, there is no description of what the variable `$(vmImageName)` refers to, and following the steps is no longer possible, since using the visual interface uses Helm, which would confuse me even more.

I am building the container like this:

```
- job: BuildSQL
  displayName: Build SQL Server Container image
  pool:
    vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
  steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        dockerfile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Code/Database/Docker/Dockerfile"
        arguments: -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/xxx.sql.tar
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        repository: his.sql
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    #publish the results of the previous task as manifest to be picked up by the deployment job
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'his.sql.tar'
        path: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

During the next stage, if want to pick up the artifact and then deploy it:

```
 - stage: DeploySQL
    displayName: 'Deploy SQL Container to AKS'
    dependsOn: BuildSQL
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy job
      pool:
        vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
      environment: 'sql-test.default'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              inputs:
                artifactName: 'manifests'
                downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/xxx.sql.tar'
```

The deployment job then fails with the following error message:

```
##[error]Pipeline does not have permissions to use the referenced pool(s) . For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.
```

I am at a loss here and don't know what the pool actually refers to and what to enter there. How can I push this to my provisioned AKS cluster in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue actually could be with quotes you have here `vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"`, please try change it to `vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'`.

In terms of passing pool as variable you should keep in mind that:

> Use only global level variables for defining a pool name. Stage/job level variables are not supported to define pool name.

However, if my first advice doesn't help please check [this article](https://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2020/03/10/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-authorization-problem/).

As you may need to permission to Default pool

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help. If you don't have a strong preference for `ubuntu-latest`, then don't specify a `vmImage` at all! Microsoft will supply a private pool with no demands.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#pool

If you do have specific demands, you can add the `demands:` line to your 'pool` section.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml